# How to grab failed Informatica Cloud Insert/Update into SFDC?

Tags: integration, error, informatica

There is a insert/update into SFDC using informatica cloud.Informatica reads a queue and if there is any item in queue it updates/inserts into the SFDC. I have created a Log Object in SFDC to record all the Updates and insert coming through informatica. I would also like to record any failed attempt by informatica to insert/update SFDC. Any suggestions on approach to record the failed attempt? I am currently trying the before Update/Insert trigger but cannot get into the catch statement.